# How do I create a user wallet in Stripe?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I’m trying to create a wallet for a user in Stripe. Other uses can donate into another user’s wallet and that user can withdraw the funds into their account. This account should remain untouched by the account owner and controlled by the software.

This will need to be seperate from the primary account which holds funds for subscriptions from users which the Stripe account owner can withdraw (income).

Is this possible with Stripe/Stripe Connect and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What you are looking for is Stripe Connect (since you are building a market place). Not sure it could help, but I just created a small Laravel helper for this kind of need: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-stripe-connect. Still you have to contact Stripe Sales to know more about Stripe Connect to learn more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd indeed need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for this.

This isn't really a programming question so you likely won't find much help here. You should reach out Stripe's support directly at https://support.stripe.com/email and explain your business model with as much details as you can (who you are, who your users will be, where are you and they located, what would a sample transaction look like, etc.). They will be able to guide you and help you design your payment flow using Stripe's API.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wallet by using charge feature of stripe i.e. for nodeJs it is  `stripe.charges.create({})` function.

It may vary depending upon your language of choice. You can prompt the user to recharge his wallet and create a charge through which you can transfer the amount to the admin account use a parameter in your db to store the user's current wallet balance for each payment deduct the required amount from the said user's account and add it to the other user's account.

[Click here for more details](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) !
Cheers!

Comment: I didn't get you , the code I provided was from stripe's official documentation . It wasn't the whole picture , Please read what I wrote in the comment and you'll understand. If you still end up with any confusion , please let me know ! Cheers !